# Execute statement with timeout?

Tags: powershell

Running into a problem using `Invoke-WmiMethod` in a script, which when run against some computers just hangs. What I'd like to do is execute the command and if it does not return within some defined period of time (say 60 to 120 sec's) then move on (logging the bailout to a file as well.) The only way I currently know to try to do this is using the `-AsJob` parameter; however, when I try that, the spawned job immediately fails (even against computers where the `Invoke-WmiMethod` statement is working without the `-AsJob` parameter added.) Other WMI-related cmdlets do work against these problem machines, so I don't think it's a auth or DCOM problem.

Anyways, are there other ways of setting a timeout on a statement in a script that I can try?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, not sure why `Invoke-WmiMethod` fails but perhaps `Invoke-Command` will work (worth a quick try I guess) e.g.:

```
$job = Invoke-Command -cn $computers { Invoke-WmiMethod ... } -AsJob
Wait-Job $job -Timeout 60
```

This does assume you have enabled remoting on all the remote computers and that they are running PowerShell 2.0.  Make sure you run this from an elevated prompt if on Vista/Windows 7 or as admin on XP.

Comment: Finally got an error on the hanging `Invoke-WmiMethod` statement -- `Invoke-WmiMethod : The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)` -- so will have to look into that. I don't have PS/WinRM 2.0 on all target PCs, so that's not really an option for me...